# text-decoration: none on <a> tag around an Image shows colors in IE but not on Chrome,Firefox etc

Tags: css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, safari

I cannot figure out why IE shows following website with each frame encapsulated with the colors of links:
http://wilson-thun.substans.com/introduction.aspx

This doesn't happen in Chrome and Safari. Can anyone please help me in explaining this occurrence?

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

I think that is css issue...

1. IE does not support "box-shadow"..
2. In this case - if you do not specify anything for images - IE will show borders where as chrome/firefox/safari will not show borders. To show the image without border everywhere you need to put BORDER="0" in the img tag.

Cheers

Comment: @Maal: BOX-Shadow won't work in IE8 and below. See my answer above.

Answer (score 0):

I've run into this issue before. Try adding `border: 0;` to link's css.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. Adding the border: "0" to the img tag works.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
a {
outline: none;
border: none;
}

a:active {
outline: none;
border: none;
}
```

Apply this to your CSS Document.

Comment: And. If you want IE To support box-shadow check out CSS3PIE at: http://css3pie.com/